# What Content-Length to put when preforming GET request?

Tags: php, http, curl, header, http-headers

I know that when preforming POST Curl u set the content length using `strlen($postdata)`

However, when doing GET how can I determine the content length?

This is my code :

```
   curl_setopt($CR, CURLOPT_URL, CLASS::SENDURL.$get);
   curl_setopt($CR, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
   curl_setopt($CR, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt($CR, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
   curl_setopt($CR, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,    
     array('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8',
                                                //'Content-Length: '.strlen($get),
                                                    'Content-Length: 0 ',
                                            //  
                                                )); 
 curl_setopt($CR, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
```

Anyone knows how I can do that?

Comment: I see you commented out `strlen($get)` did that not work for you? did you try `strlen(CLASS::SENDURL.$get)` ?

Comment: Yes i've tried both, and none worked. was that what i was supposed to do though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is *usually* no entity body (casually called content) in a GET request. You do not appear to be sending any content and can probably omit the calls to set anything content related.

Comment: …thus there shouldn't be a `content-length` request header at all… or a `Content-Type` header.

Comment: But i'm trying to send to a web service that expects content length, if i send no content length i get error 500.

Comment: @eric.itzhak — Then your problem is that either the web server does not expect GET requests at all (and is failing to respond with a "Method Not Allowed" response) or it is just buggy. Its rather hard to tell you how to work around bugs in an unspecified web service.

Comment: @eric.itzhak Have you inspected the exact messages sent and received? Most browsers allow you to do this somehow.

Comment: Ya ok this answers the question enough, didn't know if i was supposed to send `content-length`... Thanks!